# Regular expression to search for specific Referer in HTTP Header

Tags: regex

I need to create a regular expression to match everything except a specific URL for a given Referer. I currently have it to match but can't reverse it and create the negative for it.

What I currently have:

```
Referer:(http(s)?(:\/\/))?(www\.)?test.com(\/.*)?
```

In the list below:

```
Referer:http://www.test.online/
Referer:https://www.test.online/
Referer:https://www.test.tv/
Referer:https://www.blah.com/
Referer:https://www.test.com/
Referer:http://www.test.com/
Referer:http://test.com/
Referer:https://test.com/
```

It will match:

```
Referer:https://www.test.com/
Referer:http://www.test.com/
Referer:http://test.com/
Referer:https://test.com/
```

However, I would like it to match everything except for those.

This is for our WAF so unfortunately are restricted on the usage which can only be fulfilled searching for the HTTP Header being passed back.

Comment: Please add programming language you are using to tags

Comment: Try using a negative lookahead `^(?!Referer:(https?(:\/\/))?(www\.)?test\.com).+`

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird - that worked perfectly. Just couldn't find the right place to put the ?!

Comment: @AdnanAhmad You are welcome. I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string and use a negative lookahead to assert what is on the right is not what you want to match.

Note that you have to escape the dot to match it literally and you could omit the last part `(\/.*)?`.

If you don't use the capturing groups for later use you might also turn those into non capturing groups `(?:)` instead.

```
^(?!Referer:(https?(:\/\/))?(www\.)?test\.com).+$
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/4RAlZD/1)

About the pattern

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead to assert what is on the right does not match

  - `Referer:(https?(:\/\/))?(www\.)?test\.com` Match your pattern
- `)` Close negative lookahead
- `.+` Match any char except a newline 1+ times
- `$` Assert end of the string

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
^(?!.*Referer:(http(s)?(:\/\/))?(www\.)?test.com(\/.*)?).*$
```

A good way to negate your regex is to use negative lookahead.

Explanation:

The negative lookahead construct is the pair of parentheses, with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark and an exclamation point. Inside the lookahead [is any regex pattern].

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/QJfeBB/1